# Why buy an annuity contract instead of invest the money?

Tags: dividends, annuity

Inspired by [Why buy an annuity contract when you have money to spend?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/160993/why-buy-an-annuity-contract-when-you-have-money-to-spend)

Take the contract described in that question: you have $100k, and you are buying a contract that pays you $600/month for the rest of your life.

$600/month equates to $7200/year, or 7.2% on your $100k. It's very much possible to make more than 7.2% returns in the market, in fact the [S&P500 has historically returned 10.26% per year](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/042415/what-average-annual-return-sp-500.asp), so why would anyone buy the annuity contract? By buying an index fund, you both earn more and never use up the principal.

It's arguable that the market is too volatile for this kind of purpose. After all, if the market goes down 30% this year, then withdrawing $600 means you are selling during a market downturn and you might not get your 10.26% return even if the market goes up 50% next year. However, one can still buy a high-yield dividend stock. For example Altria, as of time of writing, has [9.5% dividend yield](https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=MO&p=d). That's once again better than the 7.2% payment from the annuity. One could argue that Altria's dividend is not secure, but they've been consistently paying an increasing dividend for 50+ years. It's of course possible that Altria will go bankrupt and not be able to pay the dividend anymore, but it's equally possible that the annuity company will go bankrupt and not be able to pay the $600/month. Plus, this preserves your money regardless of whether you live three more months or three hundred.

Why buy an annuity?

Comment: Why isn't this a duplicate? An annuity is an insurance policy against the market crashing or your otherwise outliving your savings. If you are in a position where you aren't concerned about that, don't buy. In my case I put a relatively small amount into an annuity just as worst-case safety net and am indeed managing the rest myself; others will make other trade-offs to suit their own needs/confidence/comfort.

Comment: Annuity companies are themselves insured to continue meeting their obligations. Random investment is not. Pick your risk/return tradeoff. One size does not fit all.

Comment: The answer to the original question discusses this quite well, and you're answering it yourself in your own question, so why are you asking it?

Comment: @littleadv does it? Where?

Comment: The whole third paragraph of your question is essentially the answer. I'm not sure what it is that you're expecting to see here.

Comment: @littleadv but then we'd have that annuities are never worth it as long as 9.5% dividend yields are in the market, which is apparently not the case (or the companies would've folded already).

Comment: Yes. Annuities are never worth it as long as you can guarantee that you can choose investments better than the insurance company.

Comment: @littleadv write that as an answer, then.

Comment: Just look up how many of the companies that paid over 7% dividend 20 years ago still do so. Then you'll approximately know the risk you're running. Not sure about you, but I don't want to start working again at 85. And the fact that *some* still do is irrelevant. It's about the odds of choosing one that will.

Comment: @DonQuiKong well they don't need to still pay 7% dividends now. As long as they paid 7% dividends at the time you bought, and they haven't reduced their dividend payments, your yield-on-cost should still be at least 7%.

Comment: *write that as an answer, then* - done.

Comment: @allure that's what I meant. Look it up, I bet your chance of grabbing a company that over 20 years stopped paying dividends or reduced them substantially is way bigger than 10%.

Comment: You know what business Altria is in, right?  Are you sure you want to bet your security in retirement on them continuing to be able to pay that dividend?

Comment: @Nobody you make it sound like it's a bad thing. I view it the other way, as the dividend is extremely reliable because of the business.

Comment: The future of the tobacco industry in the US and several other countries is very uncertain.  Even now there are members of Congress calling for some of their more popular products to be banned. If that happens, they likely won't be able to sustain their dividend.  That's why the yield is so high. It's not that the dividend is particularly large; it's that the stock price is depressed because of the uncertainty about their business. (Compare Eastman Kodak in the early 2000s, which also had a very attractive dividend yield).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no reason to buy an annuity if you can invest your money for yields better than the annuity provides for the period that the annuity covers.

Annuity is an insurance product. As explained [in the original answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/160996/2998), it is intended to mitigate longevity risk. It also mitigates bad investment risk. Whether or not it is worth paying the premium for is entirely up to you. This is no different from any other insurance product.

Answer (score 0):

Over the years, I've owned and swapped variable annuity contracts.  I had one that for annuitization purposes,  guaranteed 10% a year while the actual principal was invested in the market.

Coincidentally, the market performance was about the same as the annuitization value's growth and in that 10 year period, annuity market performance didn't trail the SPY's actual performance by much.

I rolled it into another variable annuity because it's a way to step up the guarantee pay-out without paying for that rider.  Lower fees means less drag on performance.

In terms of numbers, I have been withdrawing 6% of the appreciated amount per year for 14 years and in two years, I'll have withdrawn all of my principal and profits and I'll be on the insurance company's dime for the rest of my life.  That was my intent when buying it (longevity risk) and I've nearly achieved it.

Comment: May I ask your age?

Comment: I am 72 years old

Comment: So you said you had an annuity guaranteed 10% a year while actual principal was invested in the market, does that mean even if the principal were to tank, you still guarantee a 10% a year for annuitization?

Comment: Yep, I was guaranteed a 100% increase in value for annuitization.  The actual investment appreciated nearly as much when I cashed out (I swapped into another annuity since the 10 year guarantee was over).

Comment: What do you mean by "I was guaranteed a 100% increase (how?) in value for annuitization"?

Comment: My comments relate to what I've done in the past. I don't know what current policies offer so some of this info may not be relevant to today. Suppose you give them $100k. They invest it in sub-accounts (sort of equivalent in concept to an ETF or mutual fund).  At the same time, there's a hypothetical deferred account for annuitization purposes.  Some common names for this are GRIP/GRUB/GMIB, depending on the company. With a 10%/10 year guarantee, the annuitization account will be worth $200k in 10 years.  That's guaranteed.  If market performance exceeds 100%, then you get the higher amount.

Comment: Say it's $250k. You can cash out at the end of the contract ($250k in your pocket). Or you can swap tax free into another annuity. Or you can annuitize the $250k (receiving a higher payout than the guaranteed $200k for annuitization). You can withdraw 6% per year from the contract. However, if there is any realized gain, it's FIFO and taxable at ordinary income rates.  Withdrawal prior to age 59-1/2 incurs a penalty.  There are a lot of moving parts to this.  There other features- for example, a step up feature, locking in high sub account values but all of these come at a price.

Comment: The more riders you add, the more the drag on market performance.  If you want the most bang for the buck, invest in the SPY. If you want protection and elimination of longevity risk, look into annuities. And FWIW, some indexed annuities can be duplicated with options, providing a better return with lower risk than what the insurance company offers you (no drag).

Comment: Why does the more riders you add, the more the drag on market performance?

Comment: Riders cost money.  The more fees you are charged, the more the drag on performance.

Comment: But isn't rider fees a one-time charge?

Comment: That may exist but in the variable annuities that I've seen, it's annual.